# Principal name is showing different after switching to Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

UserPrincipal.getName showing like cb3634be-e0e1-479e-aec9-0cb38c8a0468 this after switching to Keyclock. LDAP uid was showing when we were using LDAP. After syncing users from LDAP to KC, when the application code checks user principal name, it shows this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Keycloak considers the `preferred_username` attribute instead.

Comment: This worked fine. Can you add this as answer to this question?

Comment: Glad to know it ;-) By the way, I guess you are using the Spring Security Adapter?

Comment: It's WildFly adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak considers the `preferred_username` attribute instead.

See also:

- [[keycloak-user] spring security getting username](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-February/004796.html)